# CalledProcessError: Command [inputs] returned non-zero exit status 1.

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, sys

I have been working in this code, to be more specific i am implementing an evolutionary algorithm following this [link](https://blog.sicara.com/getting-started-genetic-algorithms-python-tutorial-81ffa1dd72f9)

2. So is this my issue I use the function check_output in 2 differents parts of the code but I got two differents outputs check this out:

   ```
   wwnnnwwwwneeennen
   b'\r\n. . . . p . . \r\n        |     \r\n. . . p-h . . \r\n      |                                                                       \r\n. . . p . . . \r\n      |       \r\np-p-h-p . . . \r\n|   *         \r\np-h-H-p-p . . \r\n        |     \r\n. . . . p . . \r\n        |     \r\n. . . . p . . \r\n        |     \r\n. . . . p-H-h \r\n              \r\nScore: 1\r\n'
   Sorting Population
   wwnnnwwwwneeennen
   Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<ipython-input-39-55bfd97a1822>", line 1, in <module>
       runfile('C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em                 bioinformatica fall/HI/HI/random path.py', wdir='C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em bioinformatica fall/HI/HI')

     File "C:\Users\kayuga\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
       execfile(filename, namespace)

     File "C:\Users\kayuga\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

     File "C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em bioinformatica fall/HI/HI/random path.py", line 238, in <module>
       main()

     File "C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em bioinformatica fall/HI/HI/random path.py", line 215, in main
       population_sorted= computePerfPopulation(population, seqs[0])

     File "C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em bioinformatica fall/HI/HI/random path.py", line 124, in computePerfPopulation
       populationPerf[individual] = fitness(individual, sequence)

     File "C:/Users/kayuga/Documents/bioinformatica/projeto em bioinformatica fall/HI/HI/random path.py", line 110, in fitness
       output = subprocess.check_output("python hpview3k.py " + sequence + " " + path, shell=True)

     File "C:\Users\kayuga\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
         **kwargs).stdout

     File "C:\Users\kayuga\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in                     run
     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

   CalledProcessError: Command 'python hpview3k.py wwnnnwwwwneeennen         hhppppphhppphppphp' returned non-zero exit status 1.
   ```

As u can see the first call works, but the second call does'nt and I don't know why.

and this is my code:

```
def fitness(sequence, path):
    output = subprocess.check_output("python hpview3k.py " + sequence + " " + path, shell=True)
    a = [int(s) for s in output.split() if s.isdigit()]
    return a[0]


def computePerfPopulation(population, sequence):

    populationPerf = {}

    print("Sorting Population")

    for individual in population:

        print(individual)
        populationPerf[individual] = fitness(individual, sequence)

    return sorted(populationPerf.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

and this block belongs to the main:

```
   population = generateFirstPopulation(100, seqs[0])

    print(population[0])

    ok = subprocess.check_output("python hpview3k.py " + seqs[0] + " " + population[0], shell=True)

    print(ok)
    while(1):
        population_sorted= computePerfPopulation(population, seqs[0])
        print(population_sorted)
        breeders = selectFromPopulation(population_sorted, 25, 25)
        #population2 = createChildren(breeders, 2, seqs[0])
        #mutatedPop = mutatePopulation(population2, 20)

       # population = breeders + mutatedPop
```

I hope someone can help me
cheers

Comment: Well guys. Recheck my parameters and I figured out that I have sent the wrong parameters.